# How to save file descriptor in a folder with python?

Tags: python

I'v uploaded a file, to a python function, now I have both the filename and the file descriptor, I want to save it to another local folder (linux)

I'v tested this code, but the file I save is empty :

```
filename = request.POST['file'].filename #file descriptor
input_file = request.POST['file'].file # file name

path = "/new_folder"
fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
file = open(fullpath, "w")
file.close()
```

Can You help PLease ?

Comment: It's not clear question for me. Looks like you can just... copy that file. ``from shutil import copyfile`` and then ``copyfile(src, dst)``. More about it in [docs.python.org – shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

Comment: indeed, I'm not writing anythting to it, I do have the file descriptor, how can I do that ?

Comment: Iv tried copyfile, it requires paths, I do not have 'src', just the file fd, it didn't work!

Comment: Then maybe you should try ``os.sendfile``? [manual–os.sendfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sendfile) I think it could help. By the way – I need to do my own staff now, so I hope it'll help (or somebody else would). I'll check that question in the evening (what mean few hours). Good luck! ;)

Comment: I shouldn't try to help when I'm on the go... I'm sorry if I'm not clear or don't understand problem. So – don't take my "solutions" too seriously, please. I can be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd Found out how to do it

I was missing this part :

```
with open(fullpath,"w") as fw :
        fw.writelines(input_file.readlines())
```

Anyway, Thank you Guys :)